# Counting similar elements from a table

Tags: python

I have a table where the digits represents the something like a score where the alphabets are something like names. Example, in the first list, X scores 1 and Y scores 1.

```
L = [['X','Y','1','1'],['C','A','1','2'],['X','Z','2','2']]
```

My aim is to find similar results between two teams. Example, X had a draw with Y in the first list and also X had a draw with Z in the third. That makes my output:

```
X: 2 (because X has 2 games of draw)
Y: 1 (because Y has 1 game of draw)
C: 0
A: 0
Z: 1 (because Z has 1 game of draw)
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
L = [['X','Y','1','1'],['C','A','1','2'],['X','Z','2','2']]
dct = {}

for i in L:

    dct[i[0]] = int(i[2])
    dct[i[1]] = int(i[3])

    if int(i[2]) == int(i[3]):
       dct[i[0]] += 0
       dct[i[1]] += 0
    else:
       dct[i[0]] = 0
       dct[i[1]] = 0

for i, occurences in dct.items():
    print(i, ':', occurrences)
```

It returned me:

```
X:2
Y:1
C:0
A:0
Z:2 (wasn't supposed to be 2 but 1)
```

My mistake is probably at the 6th and 7th line or maybe my concept is wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following the logic in the code. `dct` is going to be the total of the draws they had, right? For every 'game result' in the list, you're set the contents of `dct` to be their score, then if it's a draw adding `0` and if it's not a draw, setting it to `0`, so you're not counting the draws at all

Comment: Is your if/else condition inside the for loop or its the indentation problem during copy paste?

Answer (score 1):

you begin to assign the number of draws with the score of the draw in

```
dct[i[0]] = int(i[2])
dct[i[1]] = int(i[3])
```

you should probably initialize those with `0` - if the key `i[0]` (`i[1]`) is not in `dct` yet.

python offers a nice [Counter class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for this kind of thing:

```
from collections import Counter

score = Counter()

L = [['X','Y','1','1'],['C','A','1','2'],['X','Z','2','2']]

for lst in L:
    if lst[2] == lst[3]:
        score[lst[0]] += 1
        score[lst[1]] += 1

    # make sure we also have the zero scores
    else:
        if lst[0] not in score:
            score[lst[0]] = 0
        if lst[1] not in score:
            score[lst[1]] = 0

print(score) # Counter({'X': 2, 'Z': 1, 'Y': 1, 'A': 0, 'C': 0})
```

---

if you don't want to user `Counter` here is how you could fix your code:

```
for i in L:

    if i[0] not in dct:
        dct[i[0]] = 0
    if i[1] not in dct:
        dct[i[1]] = 0

    if i[2] == i[3]:
        dct[i[0]] += 1
        dct[i[1]] += 1
```

Comment: Yes counter worked well. But, i would like to not use counter for this since I haven't been using it much recently. I knew my problem was assigning the score in the early stage as you pointed out. Care to explain on how would i initialise with 0? I think that would help with the rest.